# DOS Copy File up multiple directories

Tags: copy, dos

I can't figure out how to copy a file in Windows Dos up multiple directories. Basically I want to replicate this linux command for windows

cp ../../../Dir/Item.o Item.o

Basically I need to copy an item that is up 3 folders from a folder called "Dir" into my current directory. I use this (in linux) as part of a build step and would like to do the same for windows. I have tried changing ".." and it didn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's is almost the same on Windows. You need the correct command, and you need to use back slash instead of forward slash

```
copy ..\..\..\Dir\Item.o Item.o
```

Comment: ah, well yes i was using copy but i had the "/" instead of "\". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
copy ..\..\Dir\Item.o .
```

You need to use the back-slash as directory separators.  `.` denotes the current directory